# Is there a way to not render tooltip if button is enabled in react?

Tags: reactjs

I only want to show the tooltip if the button is disabled. When the button is enabled, I do not want to show the tooltip. How can this be done?

Comment: could you share your code on sandbox?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the state to manage whether button is disabled or not. If `disabled` is `true` then `title` will be empty.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button disabled={showTooltip} title={showTooltip ? "Button ToolTip": ""} >Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```